# Set up logger level in Spring boot app

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logging

How can I set debug logger level to disable writing to console springframework and hibernate debug messages?

In my app.yml:

```
logging:
    file: direct_delivery.log
    level:
#        root: DEBUG
        springframework:
            web: INFO
        org:
            hibernate: INFO
    pattern:
        file: '%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n'
```

When I enable debug level for root logger app showing all debug messages, but I need to check only my messages.

UPD
My config file:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public Logger logger(){
        Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger("PlanningDirectDeliveryApplication");

        return log;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set root logger to WARN level and your package to Debug . Hibernate can also write into stdout which is not leverageble in this way, you need another workaround for it.

Comment: How I can do this? **logging.level.com.company.project: DEBUG**?

Answer (score 0):

From your question it's unclear to me what exactly you want to log and what not, but generally, you can set the log level separately for every package in your application code, including your code and code of the libraries you use.

In your config file above, you are setting the log level for the `springframework.web` package and for the `org.hibernate` package to `INFO`. Although, the package `springframework.web` does not exist in Spring, so this will probably be ineffective. You probably should use `org.springframework.web` instead.

Comment: I need to show debug messages from Autowired logger which declared as Bean in my config.

Answer (score 0):

`org.hibernate` - is basically a logger name (usually the source class name (often abbreviated). The spring package name is wrong, so you don't source have classes with such name. This is the reason your logger ignored. `org.springframework` is a proper name for Spring packages.

Try to set-up logging like:

```
logging:
    file: direct_delivery.log
    level:
        root: DEBUG
        org:
            hibernate: INFO
            springframework:
                web: INFO
    pattern:
        file: '%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n'
```

Or

```
logging:
    file: direct_delivery.log
    level:
        root: DEBUG
        org.hibernate: INFO
        org.springframework.web: INFO
    pattern:
        file: '%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n'
```

Maybe you would like even declare entire `org.springframework`, not just `web` to `DEBUG` level. because setting up the logging level only for `web` you still will get logs from the `spring-web` artifact from other `Loggers` with different class sources, for example `org.springframework.http` and etc.